# IE7 problem with drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have built a dropdown menu on a site that works perfectly in IE8 and the usual Firefox, chrome and safari.

However in IE7, the menu seems to sit behind the page when i use it?
Has anyone come across something like this before?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: code/url/example please.. always be **specific** about your problem.

Comment: I encountered the same problem when I tried to embed google maps using javascript. The dropdown menu would sit behind the map.

Comment: What code would you need me to provide?

Comment: Either give us a link to your page (if possible) or a code snippet with relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: so? did the suggestions work?

Answer (score 0):

Set a z-index of 1 on the nested `ul` assuming it's positioned `relative` or `absolute` and assuming there aren't any positioned siblings with z-indexes higher.